# Путь к преобразованному виджету Qt

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

Всем привет, у меня есть виджет, который я преобразовываю в кастомный через дизайнер, но меня напрягает, что приходится вот так писать путь ужасно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл в сборщике явно подключается, если что, но всё равно нельзя написать в файле формы просто `#include "suppliercombobox.h"`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Форма `#include "suppliercombobox.h"` подразумевает, что включаемый файл находится в той же папке, что и файл с этой директивой. Вам следует указывать относительный путь или как-то по-другому компоновать файлы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в файл `pro` директиву:

```
INCLUDEPATH += src/forms/order
```

Теперь можете писать #include и просто указывать имена заголовочных файлов из данной директории

Comment: Спасибо тебе, дружище)